# How to get capital letter with graphic accent? E.g. when I type Á I get á

Tags: text

When I type in a text cell the word ANÁLISE I get in the screen ANáLISE. This occur in every word with ' ~ ^ .

This problem just occur in Mathematica.

Comment: Try `< escape > A' < escape >` or use the special characters pallete.

Comment: Do not work. I discovered something: this cell is set in Options, FontVariations, CapsType to AllCaps and this do not work. When I set this to Normal I can go to the cell and type Á and it works.